# Connected-React-Router: After awaiting an async call in action creator, push changes the url but not the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-router-v4

I am using connected-react-router 4 and am trying to dispatch a push action to change routes after awaiting successful authentication.

Routes.js:

```
export default () =>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/todos" component={Todos} />
    <Route component={Missing} />
  </Switch>;
```

Protected.js:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    rest.signedInUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    signedInUser: state.auth.signedInUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(ProtectedRoute);
```

App.js:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
            <Routes />
          </PersistGate>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

actions.js:

```
export async function login(form, dispatch) {

  try {
    await Auth.signIn(form.email, form.password);

    dispatch(reset('LoginForm'));
    dispatch(setSignedInUser(form));
    dispatch(push('/todos'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

When I call the login action with the await call, the form resets, signedInUser is updated in the store, and the url updates to /todos. However, the login component is not removed, and thus, the todos component is not rendered. Yet, when I remove the await call, the todos component is rendered as expected.

Note that the login action is used as a submit function in handleSubmit using redux-form, thus the appearance of dispatch as an argument.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How `Auth.signIn` looks like?

Comment: @Dario - `Auth.signIn` is a method from AWS Amplify.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @jmpolitzer?

Comment: @jmpolitzer, did the problem solved, if yes , can u explain how? im stucked here